# How to link input data to list items

Tags: python, list, linker

Writing a Python program - scenario is Chinese restaurant, orders are input with integers which correspond to menu items and prices. Can't work out how to link the input numbers to the corresponding menu item and price.  Have two lists, one for menu and one for price. User inputs 1 if they want rice, etc. Want to show an order summary which shows the menu item and the price and creates a total for the whole order.

Looked in Python books but can't find how to solve my problem

```
menu = ['rice', 'egg fried rice', 'prawn crackers']
price = [1.00, 2.00, 1.50]
again = True
```

---

```
while again:


    incorrect_menu_item = True

    while incorrect_menu_item:
        menu_item = int(input('Enter menu item: '))

        if menu_item >=1 and menu_item <= len (menu):
            incorrect_menu_item = False
            print('menu item accepted')
            new_order.append(menu_item)
            new_order.sort()

        else:
            print('incorrect input')

    another_item = input('Another item? n to stop, enter to continue: ')
    if another_item == 'n':
            again = False
            print('Thank you, order is complete')
```

Have tried to link the input number to the index of the menu and price lists but it is not working

Comment: use a `dict` to do it

Comment: OK...you mean create a dictionary, not two lists?  Then how do I link the dictionary items to the numbers input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way you could do this is using an array of dictionaries, a set of key value pairs. It could look a bit like this:

```
menu = [
    {
        "index": 59,
        "name": "Plain rice",
        "price": 1.2
    },
    {
        "index": 33,
        "name": "Something else",
        "price": 2.5
    }
]
```

You could then query this like so:

```
for i, item in enumerate(menu):
    if item["index"] == menu_item:
        # Do something with the correct item
        # e.g: item["price"] to get the price
```

Comment: @StTebb does this help?

Comment: Might be easier to do something like:
`menu = {
    1: ['rice', 1.00],
    2: ['egg fried rice', 2.00],
    etc etc
}
`
so it's easy to look up ordered items in the dictionary
`for item in new_order:`   \
    `item_details = menu[item]`  \
    # do something, make a list and append or print or whatever
`

Comment: Peter, you code gives me this error  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: @StTebb My fault, sorry! Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Wow thanks to both this should help @jojo have managed to print out the details of the order...just need to work out how to get the price and total it...thanks again this is a great help

Comment: thanks Peter for taking the time to edit your response

Comment: @StTebb That's ok! :-)

Comment: Fantastic!!!! used Peter's suggestion and now have it working - can print the menu items in the order and get the total price...........thanks so much